# How to access CSV file within WAR using H2's CSVREAD() function/query?

Tags: java, sql, database, csv, h2

I'm trying to read a CSV file from within a web application (Tomcat 5.5.x) and all I get is 'FileNotFoundExceptions's:

```
dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('csvfile.csv');");
```

I don't think I can/need to specify an absolute path (it will be deployed into a Linux/Tomcat server I won't have access to) and am unsure of the file protocol necessary ('jar:file', classpath: etc).

The file is under "**/WEB-INF/classes/csvfile.csv"

Any ideas on the structure of the path I need to pass to CSVREAD()?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try to dynamically build the query, first retrieving the full path with `ServletContext.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/classes/csvfile.csv")`.

Comment: This works as documented, thanks! JFYI, to get access to the ServletContext, I had to implement Spring's 'org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware' interface. My business class is an annotated POJO, used to create a web service, so no Servlet-subclasses are directly involved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

H2 currently doesn't support loading files from the classpath. However, you should be able to get the URL of the resource using:

```
String url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("csvfile.csv").toString();
```

And then you can use this URL (in my case it's an URL starting with "file:") as follows:

```
dbStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('" + url + "');");
```

(I didn't test this in a web app however)

Comment: I guess the class could be either in a different sub-directory (e.g. `sun/jdbc/odbc`) or in a .jar, where the resource would be located too, which prevents the use of getClassLoader() to find the correct directory name.

Comment: This is now supported: `SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('classpath:/com/foo/bar/csvfile.csv')`