# Load CSV file located in the classpath for H2 Database

Tags: java, testing, h2, in-memory-database

For tests purposes, I want to create and fill some tables using SQL scripts as well as CSV files.

So I created a SQL script like this one:

```
CREATE TABLE T_FOO (
  ...
) as select * from CSVREAD('classpath:/foo.csv');
```

The `foo.csv` file exists, and is located in `src/test/resources`.

When this script is run on Eclipse (where `src/test/resources` is defined as a source directory and thus is included in the classpath), I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /foo.csv
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileSystemDisk.openFileInputStream(FileSystemDisk.java:388)
    at org.h2.util.IOUtils.openFileInputStream(IOUtils.java:708)
    at org.h2.tools.Csv.initRead(Csv.java:317)
    at org.h2.tools.Csv.readResultSet(Csv.java:217)
    at org.h2.tools.Csv.read(Csv.java:193)
    ... 49 more
```

What did I do wrong? How to use correctly the `classpath:` protocol to load a CSV file?

If I put the complete path for the file (like `... CSVREAD('C:\my-project\src\test\resources\foo.csv');`), then it works. But that's not why I want to do :)

Note that I use the latest version of H2 (**1.3.153**) as [I wanted to use the `classpath:` protocol to load my file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784859/how-to-access-csv-file-within-war-using-h2s-csvread-function-query/4790910#4790910).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even if [the official docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvread) give the `CSVREAD('classpath:/org/acme/data/address.csv')` example, [Sean Patrick Floyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342852/sean-patrick-floyd) suggested to remove the leading slash, i.e. having:

```
CREATE TABLE T_FOO (
  ...
) as select * from CSVREAD('classpath:foo.csv');
```

and this is **working**!

Comment: Hm, sounds like a bug then... I will check.

Answer (score 1):

An update to the above answer.

I tried the solution provided above however I was still getting the error, then I tried the below and it works.

```
Create table tblcountry as select * from CSVREAD('classpath:/country.csv');
```

The H2 database document needs to be updated.